# C# code to get automate response from a url that requires username and password when the URL is requested via web

Tags: c#

When I request a page (say: http://mysite.com/mypage) via browser address bar then it prompts me a message [like: Authentication Required: The server http://mysite.com/mypage:80 requires a username and password...]. When I provide my username and password then it shows the response to the browser. Otherwise it says: User not authorized.

I want to automate this process using C# code so that I can get the response in my code. Since it is prompting username and password so I'm unable to get response via HttpWebRequest/Response.

I've tried with following code block:

```
       HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(myUrl) as HttpWebRequest;

       webRequest.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;

        webRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
        webRequest.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
        System.IO.Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

        System.IO.StreamReader sReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream);
        Console.WriteLine(sReader.ReadToEnd());
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the response header

for more info check here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.headers.aspx

Comment: It returns the following header: no-cache X-something-Cache: hit X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE7 Transfer-Encoding: chunked Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store,private Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Date: Fri, 06 Jul 2012 08:41:42 GMT Expires: now Last-Modified: Wed, 20 Jun 2012 14:15:53 GMT Server: nginx/0.8.53

Answer (score 0):

```
string formParams = string.Format("user={0}&password={1}&switch=Log+In", username, password);
            WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(Login_Page_URL);
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
            req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
            {
                os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
            resp = req.GetResponse();
            cookieHeader = resp.Headers["Set-cookie"];
            resp.Close();

// to view the page behing login page

            WebRequest getRequest = WebRequest.Create(Page_Behing_login_Page_URL);
            getRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookieheader);
            WebResponse getResponse = getRequest.GetResponse();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                pageSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

Try this.

Comment: It got exception on line "WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();". Error:  The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed

Comment: try to use `HTTPWebResponse` instead of `WebResponse'

Comment: Is the page you r trying to access is a page on a http remote server or on a local host

Comment: I've tried using HttpWebResponse but the result is same. The page is on the remote server

Comment: try to check the credentials you are passing.
`user={0}&password={1}&switch=Log+In' this line might not exaclty be same for yoe website too.

Comment: thanks akhil for advise. It doesn't work on changing parameter too. I found that the website requires basic authentication. I've found the solution.

Comment: Very Nice But You should also Post Your answer in case others need reference. And then mark it as accepted

Comment: Yes akhil I've already posted the answer. I was unable to answer my own question before passing 8hrs of my asking question.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I came to the solution. The site I was requesting needs basic IIS authentication. Which I've solved in the following way:

```
        WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(finalUrl);
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
        CredentialCache credentialCache = new CredentialCache();
        credentialCache.Add(new System.Uri(finalUrl), "Basic", new NetworkCredential(userName, password));

        webRequest.Credentials = credentialCache;
        webRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

        System.IO.Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

        System.IO.StreamReader sReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream);
        pageSource = sReader.ReadToEnd();
```